# c++ Jsoncpp errors

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <json/json.h>   
using namespace std;
static size_t writecallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

std::string ReadWebsite(const char* URL)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writecallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
           printf("Error");
        }

        curl_easy_strerror(res);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();

       // printf(readBuffer.c_str());

        return readBuffer;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value root;
    std::string text = ReadWebsite("https://pastebin.com/raw/PW13MZjp");
    if (reader.parse(text.c_str(), root)) {
        cout << root["addresses"];
    }
}
```

C4996: 'Json::Reader' Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

C4996: 'Json::Reader::__autoclassinit2' Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

C4996: 'Json::Reader::Reader' Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

C4996: 'Json::Reader::parse' Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

if i use CharReader and CharReadBuilder i get a Exception thrown at 0x79781F4C (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Code with CharReader and CharReadBuilder

```
int main()
{
    std::string Reply = ReadWebsite("https://pastebin.com/raw/PW13MZjp");
    const auto rawJsonLength = static_cast<int>((Reply).length());
    JSONCPP_STRING err;
    Json::Value root;

    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader(builder.newCharReader());
    if (!reader->parse((Reply).c_str(), Reply.c_str() + rawJsonLength, &root,&err)) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"error","error",MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s\n\n",root["offsets"]["ls_offset"]);
    system("pause");
}
```

Any help ill accept. Thanks!

Comment: ¿Have you tried using `CharReader` or `CharReaderBuilder`?

Comment: Head the advise. Do not use Json::Reader, use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

Comment: And if those are throwing an error, show us the code where you took the advice.